# Cannot command irobot create 2

Tags: irobot-create

This might be a dumb question. I have started to play with this robot with raspberry pi two days ago. I did some simple stuff, like- move around and sensor reading etc. But since yesterday night, It seems like I cannot send any command. The built in clean, dock functions are working perfectly but I cannot do anything using the same python code that I already used before. Its behaving like nothing is going through the Rx.

Can you suggest what might go wrong? Thanks

Comment: This question is too vague for us to help you. Please post your code, and motivate your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you may have switched the baud rate at some point. Try resetting the robot (press dock and spot at the same time for ~10 seconds, or take the battery out and put it back in).

This will cause the baud rate to go back to the default 115,200